# how to pass html in json request in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

when i am sending the request like below the response was getting successfully.

```
{
 "contractId": "siva8978",
 "html": "<p>PREFERENCE SHAREHOLDER AGREEMENTTHIS AGREEMENT is made on the&nbsp;$$Contract Start Date$$ BETWEEN&nbsp;CRADLE WEALTH SOLUTIONS PTE. LTD. (ACRA Registration No. 201427834G) of 12 Marina Boulevard #17-01 Marina Bay Financial Centre Singapore (018982) (hereinafter referred to as the Company) represented by its Consultant,&nbsp;$$Agent Name$$ (NRIC no. $$NRIC/Passport Number$$) of the one part AND $$Agent Name$$ (NRIC no.$$NRIC/Passport Number$$) of , $$Subscription Amount$$ Singapore&nbsp;$$No of Preference Shares$$ (hereinafter referred as the Preference Shareholder) of the other part.(Hereinafter the parties shall be individually referred to as the Party and jointly referred to as the Parties)</p>"

}
```

but when i am sending the request like below(extra paragraph tag in the middle of the content) the response was not  getting.

```
{
  "contractId": "siva8978",
  "html": "<p>PREFERENCE SHAREHOLDER AGREEMENT </p>

   <p>THIS AGREEMENT is made on the&nbsp;$$Contract Start Date$$ BETWEEN&nbsp;CRADLE WEALTH SOLUTIONS PTE. LTD. (ACRA Registration No. 201427834G) of 12 Marina Boulevard #17-01 Marina Bay Financial Centre Singapore (018982) (hereinafter referred to as the Company) represented by its Consultant,&nbsp;$$Agent Name$$ (NRIC no. $$NRIC/Passport Number$$) of the one part AND $$Agent Name$$ (NRIC no.$$NRIC/Passport Number$$) of , $$Subscription Amount$$ Singapore&nbsp;$$No of Preference Shares$$ (hereinafter referred as the Preference Shareholder) of the other part.(Hereinafter the parties shall be individually referred to as the Party and jointly referred to as the Parties)</p>"

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the backslashes for the multiline string like :

```
{
  "contractId": "siva8978",
  "html": "<p>PREFERENCE SHAREHOLDER AGREEMENT </p> \
   \
   <p>THIS AGREEMENT is made on the&nbsp;</p>"
 }
```

Or also you could use backticks ``` like :

```
{
  "contractId": "siva8978",
  "html": `<p>PREFERENCE SHAREHOLDER AGREEMENT </p>

   <p>THIS AGREEMENT is made on the&nbsp;</p>`
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second example is bad non-parsing JSON.

If you want to separate out the paragraphs why not use an array:

```
{
  "contractId": "siva8978",
  "html": [
    "<p>PREFERENCE SHAREHOLDER AGREEMENT</p>",
    "<p>Paragraph 2</p>",
    "<p>Etc</p>"
  ]
}
```